# How to change “et.al” to "等" in the bibliography section, according to cited journal's language field

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, languages, chinese

How to modify the .bst file that can automatically change "et.al" to "等" according to the referring journal's language?
If the journal's language is zh, I want to use "等" to replace "et.al".

here's part of my .bst file

```
ENTRY
{
  author
  title
  publisher
  journal
  address
  year
  date
  pages
  translator
  booktitle
  institution
  country
  url
  volume
  number
  type
  id
  note
  language
}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al" }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #3
          #1 + =
          numnames #3
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              "," *
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                { " " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Guys, my apologies if I didn't express clearly. I want the "et al." in the bibliography section at the end of the document. And I want to use the language field to determining the output of FUNCTION {bbl.etal}.

When I cite

```
@article{pedregosa2011scikit,
  title={Scikit-learn: Machine learning in Python},
  author={Pedregosa, Fabian and Varoquaux, Ga{\"e}l and Gramfort, Alexandre and Michel, Vincent and Thirion, Bertrand and Grisel, Olivier and Blondel, Mathieu and Prettenhofer, Peter and Weiss, Ron and Dubourg, Vincent and others},
  journal={Journal of machine learning research},
  volume={12},
  number={Oct},
  pages={2825--2830},
  year={2011},
  language={en}
}
```

It shows correctly in the bibliography section

```
[1]F. Pedregosa, G. Varoquaux, A. Gramfort, et al. Scikit-learn:  Machine learning in python[J].Journal of machine learning research, 2011, 12(Oct): 2825-2830
```

However, when I cite a Chinese journal, like this

```
@article{何清2014大数据下的机器学习算法综述,
  title={大数据下的机器学习算法综述},
  author={何清 and 李宁 and 罗文娟 and 史忠植},
  journal={模式识别与人工智能},
  volume={27},
  number={4},
  pages={327--336},
  year={2014},
  language={zh}
}
```

It shows "et al" instead of Chinese character "等"

```
[2]何清,李宁,罗文娟, et al.大数据下的机器学习算法综述[J].模式识别与人工智能, 2014,27(4): 327-336
```

Alse, it's not an error and I just want to do some improvement of "FUNCTION {bbl.etal}".

I'm new to this, sorry again for my inappropriate question format.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: The `.bst` file will contain a `FUNCTION {bbl.etal}` at some point (since spaces around braces are ignored, it may be safer to search for just `bbl.etal`). The function will contain something like `"et~al."`, just replace the text in the quotation marks with your translation of "et al.".

Comment: @moewe if I understand the question correctly the translation is conditional on the `language` field of the entry, so just replacing the string would not be sufficient for that.

Comment: @Mico the `.bst` in the question has a `language` field. Presumably the OP also includes this field in the entries in the `.bib` file. Currently that is probably ignored by the `.bst`, but as I understand the question is how _not_ to ignore it, i.e., how to use the `language` field in determining the output of `FUNCTION {bbl.etal}`.

Comment: @Marijn - Sorry, I missed it completely. (I'm used to field names being sorted alphabetically...)

Comment: @luxinliang I do have one question though: do you want _et al._ and 等 to appear as the cite label in the text (e.g., "as shown by Johnson et. al (2006) we know that X") or do you want the _et al._ in the bibliography section at the end of the document (Johnson et. al, A theory of X, Journal of Theories, pp 10-15, 2006)? Or maybe both? There are different functions in the `.bst` file for inline citations and for the bibliography, so the function that needs to be changed depends on this.

Comment: Note: _et al._ is a Latin phrase which is _a priori_ never translated.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I know but according to GB/T-7714 standard, I have to use "等" to cite Chinese journal and "et al" to cite English one.

Comment: @Marijn yes, you were right, and I  want the et al. in the bibliography section.

Comment: @luxinliang Ok. Out of curiosity, what does this standard recommend for documents written in French, German, Japanese, etc. ?

Comment: @PaulGaborit use "et al", I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out!

replace "FUNCTION {bbl.etal}" with

```
FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{
    language "zh" =
        { "等" }
        { "et~al" }
    if$
}
```